# Changing Local Policy "Prevent installation of removable devices "in CMD

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

How do I edit Group Policy Object "Prevent installation of removable devices" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753539(v=ws.10).aspx) in CMD?

I have a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) that is locked out as I am unable to use keyboard or mouse to as input devices when the windows login requires me to press ctrl+alt+delete. This Policy is the one causing this locked out situation as the old keyboard and mouse  which I am trying to solve. 
Current situation only allows me to use CMD to make changes to the system when I boot up with a bootable CD.

My server doesn't have PS2 port for the old type keyboard. Any other solution that can help me solve this locked out situation is also welcome :)

Comment: Remote Desktop?  Is the server on a network?

Answer (score 0):

"Prevent installation of removable devices" is part of "Administrative Templates" and therefore corresponds to a Registry key.

To find out that registry key, I searched for "Prevent installation of removable devices" within `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US\`, found `<string id="DeviceInstall_Removable_Deny">Prevent installation of removable devices</string>` in `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US\DeviceInstallation.adml`. Then I searched for `DeviceInstall_Removable_Deny` in `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\` and found it in `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\DeviceInstallation.admx`. The registry key is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions
valueName: DenyRemovableDevices
enabled Value: decimal 1
disabled Value: decimal 0
```

If you change that value, it will be overridden when the group policy is applied the next time -- most likely at boot time.
According to http://learnthat.com/prevent-group-policy-from-applying-to-your-computer/ you can avoid this by denying write permissions to that specific registry key. (Note, I did not test this!)

To change the registry offline, you can boot from a windows install CD, press `Shift`+`F10` simultaneously to open cmd, type `regedit`, select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key, click Menu `File` -> `Load Hive...`, navigate to your installations `\Windows\System32\Config\` folder and select the file named `SOFTWARE`.
Chose any key name, that doesn't already exist (e.g. `Offline_Software`) and then change the registry under that key. (e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Offline_Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions`)

When you're done, select your loaded Hive (e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Offline_Software`) and click `File` -> `Unload Hive...`

To shutdown properly, just close all windows, including the setup window.